# Catch DynamoDB [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer with boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am receiving this error from time to time when trying to connect to DynamoDB:

```
[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Is there a way to catch this specific exception? I heard it's similar to a socket error but Sentry doesnt raise a socket.error so I dont know if it could be caught this way.

import socket

```
try:
    run_query()
except socket.error, exc:
    print "Error"
```

Also I would prefer some kind of boto3's exception.